# GeoDjango distance_lte query showing inaccurate results

Tags: django, postgis, geodjango

I am trying to filter all the restaurants within a specific radius from the source location. Source location is coming from the user via GET request. Here's the code:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry
from django.contrib.gis.measure import D


latitude = request.GET['latitude']
longitude = request.GET['longitude']
radius = request.GET['radius']

point = GEOSGeometry('POINT(%s %s)' % (longitude, latitude))
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.filter(location__distance_lte=(point, D(km=radius)))

# checking the distance
for i in restaurants:
       distance = point.distance(i.location)
       print(i, distance * 100)
```

I am getting the results 80% correct but 20% wrong. Let me explain what is happening...

By running the above filter with a radius of 55km, I get the results but when I check the distance from the source location to the restaurant locations, there are a few restaurants missing that are around 52km away from the source location. I am expecting them too to be in the results when I filter it with a 55km radius.

If I increase the radius from 55km to 58km, then those missing restaurants are showing. I am unable to understand why some of the restaurants are not being pulled?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you check with `point = Point(latitude, longitude)`,  (`from django.contrib.gis.geos import Point`)?

Comment: You are computing distance in degrees, not in meters/km. Since 1 degree is (very) roughly 100km, your multiplication by 100 gives a very inaccurate estimation of the distance in km.

Comment: @JGH Oh, I see. Can you please guide me on how to make it km to get the accurate distance? Thanks for pointing out